# Posts to wall via graph api don't show when I include a link

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've created a facebook app, and authorized a user (my personal facebook account) to the app with the 'publish_stream' and 'offline_access' permissions.

Using my access token, I can post status updates to my wall (USER_ID/feed) when I include a "message" parameter by itself.

Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&message=Test

However, I need my app to post additional data, such as a link to the page which the user is sharing. No problem, right? Per the spec, I just need to include a "link" parameter with the post to the graph api.

The problem is that, as soon as I include the "link" parameter, the post never shows up on my wall! And to make matters worse, the graph api returns a post ID as if everything was ok!

Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&message=Test&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

What in the world am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked your Activity Log, if the post is in there? What’s the actual URL you’re trying to post?

Comment: The url is "http://www.beatbrokerz.com", but I've tried "http://www.google.com" as well to see if the link was being filtered by domain. And as far as the activity log goes, nothing.

Comment: Try fixing this error first: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.beatbrokerz.com%2F

Comment: That error is confusing to me since the app id that it links to is not correct. I've uploaded a screenshot of that app that I'm using to post to the graph api.

Comment: http://www.beatbrokerz.com/app-screenshot.jpg

Comment: Well, on second look, it looks like some other module in my drupal stack was inserting an app id meta tag. I changed that and the error is gone. I'll check if my problem with the graph api is fixed!

Comment: Nope. I send the post to graph api, get an id in the response, and still nothing shows on my activity log or timeline.